# Poincaré–Hopf and Morse inequalities

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, morse-theory

Disclaimer: I am not a differential geometer, so maybe this question does not make sense:

Let $(M^m,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ a Morse function. Since $g$ is pointwise non-degenerate, a obtain a vector field by $X_p:=g_p^{-1}(\mathrm{d}f|_p)$. I have two notions of “critical point” and “index”:

1. The Morse theoric one: $p\in M$ is *critical* if $\mathrm{d}f|_p=0$. The *index* $I(p)$ is the negative sign of $\mathrm{d}^2f|_p$
2. The one for Poincaré–Hopf: $p\in M$ is *critical* if $X_p=0$. The *index* $\mathrm{ind}_p(X)$ is the degree of the following map, locally around $p$ (after choosing charts and obtaining a local trivialisation of $TM$):
   $$\varphi:\mathbb{S}^{m-1}\to \mathbb{S}^{m-1}, q\mapsto \frac{X(q)}{\|X(q)\|}.$$

Obviously, the two notions of being critical are equivalent. What about the indices? They are not the same as $0\le I(p)\le m$, but not necessarily $0\le \mathrm{ind}_p(X)\le m$. In what way are they related?

The only idea I had was the combination of Poincaré–Hopf and Morse theory (correct?):
$$\sum_{\text{critical $p$}} \mathrm{ind}_p(X) = \chi(M) = \sum_{\text{critical $p$}} (-1)^{I(p)}.$$

Comment: First, the adjunction operator $g_p: T_pM \rightarrow T^*_pM$ is an isomorphism, so the definition of a critical point is the same.

Comment: You are working too hard. This is a local calculation, and one that is essentially independent of the metric - a homotopy of metrics induces a homotopy of vector fields, all of which are transverse to 0 (aka, 'the gradient flow has nondegenerate zeroes' is a statement independent of metric). So work with the Euclidean metric on a chart, and similarly that $f$ is one of the standard quadratic Morse functions $\sum \pm x_i^2$. Then a quick check shows that $(-1)^{I(p)} = \text{ind}_p$.